# Eigenfunction expansion of Gaussian kernel over a closed interval

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenfunctions, gaussian, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

$\newcommand{\Xc}{\mathcal{X}}$
Let $\Xc=[-1,1]$ and consider a Gaussian kernel $k(x,t)\propto \exp(-(x-t)^2/2\sigma^2)$ for some $\sigma>0$ on $\Xc$.
I am looking for an eigenfunction expansion of the induced integral operator $\mathbf{K}\colon L^2(\Xc)\to L^2(\Xc)$.
That is, I wish to find a countable set of functions $\{\phi_n\colon \Xc\to \mathbb{R}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that
$$
k(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda_n \phi_n(x)\phi_n(t)
$$
and $\int_{\Xc}\phi_m(x)\phi_n(x)d x=\delta_{mn}$.

Here are some related results I am aware of:

- Hermite polynomials characterize the $L^2(\rho)$-orthonormal eigenfunctions of Gaussian kernels over $\mathbb{R}$ for a Gaussian weight $\rho$ [[See Sec. 6.2]](http://www.math.iit.edu/%7Efass/PDKernels.pdf).
- Spherical harmonics characterize the $L^2(\Xc)$-orthonormal eigenfunctions of Gaussian kernels over the hypersphere $\Xc=S^{d-1}$ (for a uniform weight) [[See Thm. 2.]](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Eniyogi/papersps/MinNiyYao06.pdf).

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?